# Update value of row based on result from another table SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Table One:

```
IdOne | IdTwo
------+------
32423 |  435
2343  |  345
2344  |  45
```

Table one gets both idOne and idTwo from two other tables. IdOne stores the ids of a venue. The table from where it gets its id from stores whether or not this venue is active. Users can deactivate a venue and activate it. There are some duplicates that point to the same venue and I would like to set the value of the duplicates(in table one) to the value of the active venue I get from the table that stores this information.

I tried sub querying, correlated querying and I have not gotten far. Any help will be appreciated greatly.

EDIT:

Sorry for the badly worded question.  I was a bit frantic.  Here is the correct question.

I have two tables.  A many to many table associating performances to venues.  And a venues table.

The many to many table has the layout:

```
performance_venue 
(
    performanceId,
    venueId
)
```

The venue table has the layout:

```
venue 
(
    uniqueId,
    venueTypeId,
    active
)
```

They are related by `venue.uniqueId = performance_venue.venueId`.  There are instances in `performance_venue` that refer to `venue` instances that have an `active` value of `0`.  These `venues` that have an active value of `0` have an updated `venue` instance in which the `active` value is `1` and have the same `venueTypeId`.  So, what I would like to do is to update all the `performance_venue` instances to refer to the `venue` instances that have an `active` value of `1` if they currently are referring to a `venue` instance that has an active value of `0`.

Here is an example.

performance_venue

```
performanceId  | venueId
---------------+--------
1              | 1
2              | 2
3              | 3
```

venue

```
uniqueId | venueTypeId | active
---------+-------------+-------
1        |  1          | 0
2        |  1          | 1
3        |  2          | 1
```

Expected result after update

performance_venue

```
performanceId  | venueId
---------------+---------
1              | 2
2              | 2
3              | 3
```

Comment: Might be easier to understand if you posted your query.

Comment: did you try and look at the docs by searching "update sql server" on google?  This is explained in the update statement on MS' website.

Comment: yes I have been doing this for the past few hours. @Stephane, my query doesn't work. I need to update the inactive id column based on the results of a query that contains results of the active ids. The results do not have the same ids, the only identifier they have that this is the same venue is another key on the venue table that contains the subkey.

Comment: What does TableTwo look like? Can you post the query you're working with?

Comment: @digital.aaron table two : (unique id , location id, (venue type id(this is what helps me figure out if it is a duplicate-- if more than one venue shares this, this means the venue was added more than one time)), active) table one : (event id and venue id). in table one, i have to find the inactive venue id and replace it with its corresponding active one. i have the script that finds the inactive venues but what is hard for me is how to i update the inactive ones to active ones?

Comment: Where does TableOne.IdTwo's value come from?

Comment: @digital.aaron when I perform subquery in set, i get multiple rows and an error. my script was                                                                UPDATE [tableOne]
SET [tableOne].VenueId = ( subquery that selects venue based on whether it is active)
WHERE VenueId IN ( subquery that gets inactive venues);

Comment: @digital.aaron that comes from another table that stores event information.

Comment: What's the relationship between TableOne/TableTwo and EventTable?

Comment: TableOne has many to many relationship with both tabletwo and eventtable. EventTable's primary key is used inside table one. tabletwo's primary key is also used inside tableone. table two and event table do not have any foreign keys pointing to table one.

Comment: I will try looping and see if this works. I'll let you know if it does. thank you for taking the time to help out!

Comment: Your code example for TableOne, and your further comments above don't really mesh. It's quite difficult to follow what you're doing and what you want to do. Can you clean up the question more with better table and column names? I think I'm on the cusp of figuring out what you want to do, but I need a little more info.

Comment: @digital.aaron I edited my post! Thank you so much for attempting to help out when I was giving bad information! I was a bit frantic about not being able to solve it. I came up with a solution though! Check it out if you get the chance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.IdTwo = (SELECT top 1 t2.IdTwo FROM TableTwo t2 WHERE t2.IdOne = t1.IdOne AND t2.Active = 1)
FROM TableOne t1
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I need to update all rows, now just one and the ids are not the same, they are different, so I can not do t1.idOne = t2.idOne

Answer (score 1):

The solutoin involves constructing a table that has both the active and non-active venue in the same row.  Then you just set the `performance_venue` `venueId` to the active `uniqueId`.

`UPDATE pv
SET pv.venueId = active_uniqueId
FROM venue v
JOIN performance_venue pv ON pv.venueId = v.uniqueId
JOIN (
  SELECT venueTypeId, uniqueId as active_uniqueId
  FROM venue
) v_active ON v.venueTypeId = v_active.venueTypeId
WHERE v.active = 0 AND v.venueTypeId in (
    SELECT venueTypeId
    FROM venue v_sub
    WHERE active = 1 and v.venueTypeId = v_sub.venueTypeId
)
AND v.uniqueId != active_uniqueId`